# can cmd read what It shows to me?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using "net file" command but I want it to read its answer to the "net file" question. I know It is not a question but I am trying to explain well. If it says "no entry on the list" I want it to echo "0"

Comment: Please add [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that you might also need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Use `for /F` to capture the output of a command.  [See this page](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).  If you want to test only whether the output contains "no entries", you can use conditional execution.  Example: `net file | find "no entries" >NUL && echo 0`  [See this page](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html).

Comment: `read` - Do you mean to use Windows SAPI object? Or do you mean by `echo`ing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm here to finish the answer so the system thinks the question has an answer.

---

Your question is **very** incomplete due to the lack of code, but here is what you need.

```
for /f %%G in ('net file') do (
    echo %%G | findstr /C:"no entires on the list" >NUL && echo 0
)
```

The basic idea is explained by rojo, but I made some little adjustments.

- `for /f` loop loops through the output of `net file`
- `echo %%G | findstr` looks for the string "no entries on the list"

  - If the string does not exist, echo 0

Note the if you use the code in command-line, change `%%G` to `%G`.

Comment: are you aware that `findstr "no entries on the list"` will return any line that contains at least one of the five words?

Comment: I didn't know that!

Comment: How can I change it so it search as one string?

Comment: use `find` or `findstr /c:"complete string"`

Comment: Noted @Stephan.